Bean not getting autowired in spring boot test
In my spring boot test I have defined a ContextConfiguration that specifies the package of the bean that I want to autowire in the test:
import com.stocktrader.repository.PlaceOrderDetailsRepository;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = StockTraderServiceTest.class)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfiguration.class)
public
class StockTraderServiceTest {
  @org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
  @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.stocktrader.repository"})
  class TestConfiguration {

  }
  @Autowired
  private PlaceOrderDetailsRepository placeOrderDetailsRepository;
  . . . 
}

package com.stocktrader.repository;
@Repository
public interface PlaceOrderDetailsRepository extends JpaRepository<PlaceOrderDetails, Long> {
. . . 
}

but it doesn't get wired:
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.stocktrader.repository.PlaceOrderDetailsRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1799)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1355)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656)
    ... 59 more

What am I doing wrong?

Your test is weird. You are mixing JUnit4 and JUnit5 annotations/bootstrap. That is trouble waiting to happen. I would only expect to see the @SpringBootTest everything else should nog be there. The @SpringBOotTest should have no classes element at all.
